# JQuery search filter by specific classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I'm doing a database select and bringing all the fields from a table in divs like this:

```
<div class="card hoverable reserva">
    <div class="card-content">
        <div class="cod-reserva-lbl teal-text text-lighten-2">Reservation number.</div>
        <div class="reservation-code teal-text">00000000</div>
        <div class="reservation-item">
            <b>Car's licence plate:</b> <span class="dato">AAA-000</span>
        </div>
        <div class="reservation-item">
            <b>Person's ID:</b> <span class="dato">00000000</span>
        </div>
        <div class="reservation-item">
            <b>Departure:</b> <span class="dato">dd/mm/yyyy</span>
        </div>
        <div class="reserva-item">
            <b>Arrival:</b> <span class="dato">dd/mm/yyyy</span>
        </div>
        <div class="reservation-item">
            <b>Starting city:</b> <span class="dato">Some city</span>
        </div>
        <div class="reservation-item">
            <b>Destination city:</b> <span class="dato">Some other city</span>
        </div>
        <div class="reservation-item">
            <b>Price:</b> <span class="green-text dato">$XXXXXX</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-action card-action-reservation">
        <a href="#" class="green-text flat-small waves-effect waves-green">
            <i class="left material-icons">mode_edit</i> Edit
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="red-text flat-small waves-effect waves-red">
            <i class="left material-icons">delete</i> Delete
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The script I'm currently using goes like this:

```
//Search filter
var $rows = $('.reservation');

//#search is the input I'm using as search bar
$('#search').keyup(function () {

    var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
            reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
            text;

    $rows.show().filter(function () {
        text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
        return !reg.test(text);
    }).hide();
});
```

The problem is, if I search for "Reservation number", it will still show all of them because all of them contain "Reservation number". What I want is to be able to filter **exclusively** for the text inside the `span.dato` items. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How about `$(this).find('span.dato').text()` ?

Comment: @LJ_1102 I'm not quite familiar with the `find()` method. Should I just replace `text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');` with `text = $(this).find('span.dato').text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');`

Comment: @McSullivanD'Ander did you try that?

Comment: as a side-note, it may be more efficient to remove the up front `.show`, and instead add `.siblings().show()`  after `.hide()` so that you're only showing the ones that need to be shown, rather than showing them all, and then hiding the ones that don't match.

Comment: @KevinB yes, and it does work; will try the other thing, thanks a lot for the  comment.

Comment: @KevinB I just tried removing the `.show` ana adding `.siblings().show()` and now it only works the first time; will not show other results if I change the criteria nor will it show all the results if I clean the search bar.

Comment: weird... carry on then, :) works here: http://jsfiddle.net/4pjss89m/